# Send variables from Python Flask to HTML

Tags: python, html, flask, python-requests

I have following Problem:
i want to send some data to Html from Python with button Click in HTML, but wenn i click the button it doesn't work at all.
Here is my code:
*

> python.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, Markup, request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('new.html')

@app.route('/SomeFunction', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def SomeFunction():
    if request.method == 'GET':
         text = 'Name'  
    print("result:")
    return render_template("new.html",text = text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

> *and here is my Html:*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>The jQuery Example</title>
<div class="flashes">
  {% for message in get_flashed_messages()%}
    {{ message }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
    <h2>jQuery-AJAX in FLASK. Execute function on button click</h2>  
<script type="text/javascript" {{ url_for('static', filename='app.js')}}></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script type=text/javascript> $(function() { $("#mybutton").click(function (event) { $.getJSON('/SomeFunction', { }, function(data) { }); return false; }); }); </script> 

</head>

<body>        
        <input type = "button" id = "mybutton" value = "Click Here" />
    <p>text: {{text}}</p>

</body>    

</html>
```

So what i want is when i press the input button it will show the name what is in python defined. Maybe there are other ways what can make it works, but i need exactly in python.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so passing variables from python `flask` to `html` is easy.

```
Import json
```

make a dictionary object with key whatever you want and assign your variable to that key

```
jobj = { 'name' : name }
```

Now dump this object as `json` and pass as argument

```
return render_template('htmlfile.html', res=json.dumps(jobj))
```

Now you would be able to access the `res json` in JavaScript in `htmlfile.html`

```
<Script>

var res = JSON.parse(' {{ res | safe }} ');
console.log(res.name);

</Script>
```